# Passing variables from one template to another template

Tags: silverstripe

With Silverstripe templates, can I pass a variable from one include to another?

Within Order_ConfirmationEmail.ss `<% include Order SendingEmail=true %>`.  Set $SendingEmail to true.

And in Order.ss pass $SendingEmail to another template via another include:

`<% include Order_Content SendingEmail=$SendingEmail %>`

Then use the variable $SendingEmail in Order_Content.ss:

`<% if $SendingEmail %>We are sending an email <% end_if %>`

Unfortunately, $SendingEmail does not have a value in Order_Content.ss (it does in Order.ss).  Is this approach possible?  Is there a better way.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess would be that `$SendingEmail` likely isn't actually set in the template that has the include block. Have you checked the value of `$SendingEmail` in that parent template?

Comment: It should work according to https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/templates/syntax/#includes Did you flush? Are you sure this template is actually rendered (and not another one from a module)?

Answer (score 0):

It should. I'm not sure of all the ins and outs unfortunately, but so far as I know that is a thing (being able to pass any variable in scope). But there are a number of caveats you should probably be aware of. The biggest one being scope. If you're changing context at any point (and you have multiple layers so this is somewhat likely) you need to ensure the variable you're attempting to reference is in scope. Otherwise it will be blank, and thus report as such on any further reference to it. This is the most common  problem when it comes to templates, so it always pays to double (triple) check.